# Sublime Text 2 - mensagem de erro no python /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Tags: python, sublime-text-2

Usando o `cmd+B` (Tools -> Build) no Sublime Text 2, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''
```

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente faltou salvar o arquivo que você está querendo rodar.

Caso isso não resolva o problema, tente criar um arquivo de nome `__main__.py` no mesmo diretório do programa. Dentro dele, faça o `import` do arquivo que você quer executar.

Ex: supondo que o programa que você quer rodar esteja no arquivo `meuscript.py`, o conteúdo de `__main.py__` ficaria assim:

`import meuscript`

Answer (score 3):

Em geral este problema pode ser resolvido salvando o script antes de executá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Salve o arquivo com a extensão `.py` antes de executa-lo.